# Cannot call any library through Perl package Statistics::R

Tags: r, perl, ggplot2, cygwin

I'm working on an HTML app using Perl CGI and R (through the Perl package [`Statistics::R`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Statistics::R). My Perl script, which otherwise works, cannot load any R libraries with this code: (note that I rolled it into its own script, and has this behavior when run out of CGI)

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Statistics::R;
my $R = Statistics::R->new();
$R->run_from_file("ggplot_2.R");
$R->stopR;
```

Which calls this R script:

```
setwd("C:/cygwin64/srv/www/htdocs/images/")
library(ggplot2)
png("ggplot_output.png")
A <- data.frame(length=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,4,5,6,7,1))
B <- data.frame(length=c(2,2,1,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,2,2,1,1,1))
A$subset <- 'A'
B$subset <- 'B'
AB <- rbind(A,B)
ggplot(AB, aes(length, fill = subset)) + 
    geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, aes(y = ..density..), position = 'identity')
```

Which produces this error in apache2:

```
Problem while running this R command:
source(file.path("20140819_ggplot_2.R"))
Error:
library(ggplot2) : there is no package called â€˜ggplot2â€™
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> library
Execution halted
```

I've reinstalled ggplot2 and plyr, but that hasn't helped.

```
$R->run(qq`library(plyr)`);
```

also causes the same error, but with the 'plyr' package. How do I get Statistics::R and R libraries to work together?

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue. That last line of code with the `qq` looks really weird, though.

Comment: Do you have special .libPaths set up when you run R? Maybe print them out from Perl and compare to your interactive R session.

Comment: well, turns out that did the trick. Windows R and cygwin R don't share any .libPaths(). I couldn't get the lib.loc option to work in loading the package in Perl -- different digest.dll? -- but I installed ggplot2 under cygwin R and it works now. Should you post an answer in this case MrFlick? I feel a little silly for not thinking of that.